# Multiple Inheritance and calling super()

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, multiple-arguments

I get the error:
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

When trying to instantiate an object from the class Top:

super(Middle1, self).__init__(name, "middle")

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, name, type):
        pass

class Middle1(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Middle1, self).__init__(name, "middle1")

class Middle2(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Middle2, self).__init__(name, "middle2")

class Middle3(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Middle3, self).__init__(name, "middle3")

class Top(Middle1, Middle2, Middle3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Top, self).__init__("top")

# Here is where it produces the error
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Top()
```

What am I not understanding about this multiple inheritance issue?

Note: this is python 2.7

## EDIT

Ok so I tried something that I think works for my case. This is the equivelent end result, I think it's basically forcing depth first by not calling super and calling each individual __init__ instead.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, name, type):
        pass

class Middle1(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, type = "middle1"):
        super(Middle1, self).__init__(name, type)

class Middle2(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, type = "middle2"):
        super(Middle2, self).__init__(name, type)

class Middle3(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, type = "middle3"):
        super(Middle3, self).__init__(name, type)

class Top(Middle1, Middle2, Middle3):
    def __init__(self):
        Middle1.__init__(self, "top")
        Middle2.__init__(self, "top")
        Middle3.__init__(self, "top")

# No errors anymore
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Top()
```

Comment: This isn't technically multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance is when a class inherits from multiple parent classes directly (and is generally not supported in most programming languages).

Comment: Have you checked that the code file you are executing is the one you are showing here? Because this code does not produce that error ...

Comment: You were right. I've edited the code to show my actual situation, Now it produces that error.

Comment: I would refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance this question as well. (Your question should probably be closed as a duplicate of this one, but I think an answer based on your specific code is useful, and I hesitate to use my dupe hammer to close the question unilaterally when I am providing an answer myself.)

Comment: It's slightly different from the proposed problem. Mine would work if parents all received same arguments.

Comment: since Base doesn't call super() the implementation is actually broken ... not all of your `__init__` will be called. add a print() to each `__init__` to see this. to see why and fix this read [super() and cooperative methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714419/super-and-changing-the-signature-of-cooperative-methods/56714809#56714809)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to look at the method resolution order of `Top`:

```
>>> for c in Top.__mro__: print c
...
<class '__main__.Top'>
<class '__main__.Middle1'>
<class '__main__.Middle2'>
<class '__main__.Middle3'>
<class '__main__.Base'>
<type 'object'>
```

This helps you see which class each call to `super` represents.

Your mistake is thinking that the call to `super(Middle1, self)` refers to the (only) base class `Base` of `Middle1`. It does not: it refers to the the class following `Middle1` in the MRO of `self.__class__`. Since `self.__class__` is `Top`, the next class in line is `Middle2`, whose `__init__` takes only one argument.

To use `super` correctly from a method, you need to ensure that the method takes the same arguments in *every* class, because you cannot predict which class's method will be called by looking at the code itself; it depends entirely on the type of the object that initiates the chain of calls, which might be a class you aren't even aware of yet.

There are two posts I suggest reading:

- [Python's super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)
- [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) very carefully to understand the semantics of `super`.

Together, they give you a good understanding of when `super` can be used correctly and how to avoid the problem you see here.

(In full disclosure, I haven't read either post recently, so I will refrain from trying to summarize the advice presented in each.)

Comment: Yes that's mostly it, I expected it to go depth first and then left to right.

Comment: taking the same arguments for `__init__`  in every class is not enough, since object.__init__ does not take any parameters, so passing arguments to `super.__init__()` is broken. see [Super() and changing the signature of cooperating methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714419/super-and-changing-the-signature-of-cooperative-methods/56714809#56714809)

Comment: The links I included also discuss removing arguments from calls to `super().__init__` (or other upstream methods) to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you instantiating Top objects?

Given your code above, the following works fine:

```
   topObj = Top()
   middleObj = Middle("middle")
   baseObj = Base("base", "type")
```

Comment: I see you edited your example code. Indeed, with multiple inheritance constructor resolution becomes confusing.