# super() and changing the signature of cooperative methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super

in a multiple inheritance setting such as laid out in, how can I use `super()` and also handle the case when the signature of the function changes between classes in the hierarchy?

i.e. can I rewrite this example (in python3) to work with `super()`?

> example was taken from the article [super() considered harmful article](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/example1-1.py)

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B")

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print("C","arg=",arg)
        A.__init__(self)

class D(B):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print("D", "arg=",arg)
        B.__init__(self)

class E(C,D):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print("E", "arg=",arg)
        C.__init__(self, arg)
        D.__init__(self, arg)
```

E(10)

Comment: Please include the code instead of adding a link, and why do you think it's harmful?

Answer (score 1):

James Knight's article [super() considered harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) suggests a solution by always accepting `*args` and `**kwargs` in all cooperating functions.
however this solution does not work for two reasons:

1. `object.__init__` does not accept arguments 
   this is a breaking change introduced python 2.6 / 3.x 
   [`TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`](https://menno.io/posts/object__init__takes_no_parameters/)
2. using `*args` is actually counter productive

## Solution TL;DR

1. `super()`  usage has to be consistent: In a class hierarchy, super should be used everywhere or nowhere. is part of the contract of the class. if one classes uses `super()` all the classes *MUST* also use `super()` in the same way, or otherwise we might call certain functions in the hierarchy zero times, or more than once
2. to correctly support `__init__` functions with any parameters, the top-level classes in your hierarchy must inherit from a custom class like SuperObject:

   ```
   class SuperObject:        
       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           mro = type(self).__mro__
           assert mro[-1] is object
           if mro[-2] is not SuperObject:
               raise TypeError(
                   'all top-level classes in this hierarchy must inherit from SuperObject',
                   'the last class in the MRO should be SuperObject',
                   f'mro={[cls.__name__ for cls in mro]}'
               )

           # super().__init__ is guaranteed to be object.__init__        
           init = super().__init__
           init()
   ```
3. if overridden functions in the class hierarchy can take differing arguments, always pass all arguments you received on to the super function as keyword arguments, and, always accept `**kwargs`.

### Here's a rewritten example

```py
class A(SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("A")
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class B(SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("B")
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, age, **kwargs):
        print("C",f"age={age}")
        super(C, self).__init__(age=age, **kwargs)

class D(B):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        print("D", f"name={name}")
        super(D, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

class E(C,D):
    def __init__(self, name, age, *args, **kwargs):
        print( "E", f"name={name}", f"age={age}")
        super(E, self).__init__(name=name, age=age, *args, **kwargs)

e = E(name='python', age=28)
```

output:

```
E name=python age=28
C age=28
A
D name=python
B
SuperObject
```

## Discussion

lets look at both problems in more detail

### `object.__init__` does not accept arguments

consider the original solution given by James Knight:

> *the general rule is: always pass all arguments you received on to the super function, and, if classes can take differing arguments, always accept `*args` and `**kwargs`*.

```py
    class A:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("A")
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class B(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("B")
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class C(A):
        def __init__(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
            print("C","arg=",arg)
            super().__init__(arg, *args, **kwargs)

    class D(B):
        def __init__(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
            print("D", "arg=",arg)
            super().__init__(arg, *args, **kwargs)

    class E(C,D):
        def __init__(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
            print( "E", "arg=",arg)
            super().__init__(arg, *args, **kwargs)

    print( "MRO:", [x.__name__ for x in E.__mro__])
    E(10)
```

a breaking change in python 2.6 and 3.x has changed `object.__init__` signature so that it no longer accepts arbitrary arguments

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9001c741f80d> in <module>
     25 
     26 print( "MRO:", [x.__name__ for x in E.__mro__])
---> 27 E(10)

...

<ipython-input-2-9001c741f80d> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      7     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      8         print("B")
----> 9         super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     10 
     11 class C(A):

TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

The correct way to handle this conundrum is for the top level classes in a hierarchy to inherit from a custom class like `SuperObject`:

```py
class SuperObject:        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mro = type(self).__mro__
        assert mro[-1] is object
        if mro[-2] is not SuperObject:
            raise TypeError(
                'all top-level classes in this hierarchy must inherit from SuperObject',
                'the last class in the MRO should be SuperObject',
                f'mro={[cls.__name__ for cls in mro]}'
            )

        # super().__init__ is guaranteed to be object.__init__        
        init = super().__init__
        init()
```

and thus rewriting the example as follows should work

```py
    class A(SuperObject):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("A")
            super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class B(SuperObject):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("B")
            super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class C(A):
        def __init__(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
            print("C","arg=",arg)
            super(C, self).__init__(arg, *args, **kwargs)

    class D(B):
        def __init__(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
            print("D", "arg=",arg)
            super(D, self).__init__(arg, *args, **kwargs)

    class E(C,D):
        def __init__(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
            print( "E", "arg=",arg)
            super(E, self).__init__(arg, *args, **kwargs)

    print( "MRO:", [x.__name__ for x in E.__mro__])
    E(10)
```

output:

```
MRO: ['E', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'SuperObject', 'object']
E arg= 10
C arg= 10
A
D arg= 10
B
SuperObject
```

### using `*args` is counter productive

lets make the example a bit more complicated, with two different parameters: `name` and `age`

```py
class A(SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("A")
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class B(SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("B")
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, age, *args, **kwargs):
        print("C",f"age={age}")
        super(C, self).__init__(age, *args, **kwargs)

class D(B):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        print("D", f"name={name}")
        super(D, self).__init__(name, *args, **kwargs)

class E(C,D):
    def __init__(self, name, age, *args, **kwargs):
        print( "E", f"name={name}", f"age={age}")
        super(E, self).__init__(name, age, *args, **kwargs)

E('python', 28)
```

output:

```
E name=python age=28
C age=python
A
D name=python
B
SuperObject
```

as you can see from the line `C age=python` the positional arguments got confused and we're passing the wrong thing along.

my suggested solution is to be more strict and avoid an `*args` argument altogether. instead:

> if classes can take differing arguments, always pass all arguments you received on to the super function *as keyword arguments*, and, always accept `**kwargs`.

here's a solution based on this stricter rule. first remove `*args` from `SuperObject`

```py
class SuperObject:        
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('SuperObject')
        mro = type(self).__mro__
        assert mro[-1] is object
        if mro[-2] is not SuperObject:
            raise TypeError(
                'all top-level classes in this hierarchy must inherit from SuperObject',
                'the last class in the MRO should be SuperObject',
                f'mro={[cls.__name__ for cls in mro]}'
            )

        # super().__init__ is guaranteed to be object.__init__        
        init = super().__init__
        init()
```

and now remove `*args` from the rest of the classes, and pass arguments by name only

```py
class A(SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("A")
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class B(SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("B")
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, age, **kwargs):
        print("C",f"age={age}")
        super(C, self).__init__(age=age, **kwargs)

class D(B):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        print("D", f"name={name}")
        super(D, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

class E(C,D):
    def __init__(self, name, age, *args, **kwargs):
        print( "E", f"name={name}", f"age={age}")
        super(E, self).__init__(name=name, age=age, *args, **kwargs)

E(name='python', age=28)
```

output:

```
E name=python age=28
C age=28
A
D name=python
B
SuperObject
```

which is correct

Answer (score -1):

Please see the following code, does this answer your question?

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("A")

class B():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("B")

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("C","arg=", *args)
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class D(B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("D", "arg=", *args)
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class E(C,D):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("E", "arg=", *args)
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


# now you can call the classes with a variable amount of arguments
# which are also delegated to the parent classed through the super() calls
a = A(5, 5)
b = B(4, 4)
c = C(1, 2, 4, happy=True)
d = D(1, 3, 2)
e = E(1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, value=4)
```

Comment: unfortunately this code is wrong in the sense that calls to B.__init__ and D.__init__ aren't happening when constructing e.
just run the last line  e = E(1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, value=4) and see the missing calls